# Command npm install tns-android@3.4.1 --silent --save-exact --save failed with exit code 243

Tags: android, npm, command-line-interface, tns

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgQH8.png)

I am facing problems in making changes to the emulator.I would be thankful if someone could help.

Command npm install tns-android@3.4.1 --silent --save-exact --save failed with exit code 243

tried npm install nativescript -g , but did not work.

Following were the commands used to run the program:
npm install
sudo pm install nativescript -g
tns platform add android
tns run android

Comment: This issue is solved.

Comment: Please how did you solve it?

Comment: Please check you have proper permissions to the folder where you have installed your native script and also check you have JDK which your project supports.